# Is this possible to validate remote users and password existence check in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, active-directory, ldap

How can I validate a username and password against Active Directory? I simply want to check if a username and password are correct in nodejs code.

I have used activedirectory npm

but showing error as

```
ERROR: {"code":"ECONNREFUSED","errno":"ECONNREFUSED","syscall":"connect","address":"96.45.82.8","port":389}
```

Here is my code

```
    var ActiveDirectory = require('activedirectory');
    var config = { url: 'ldap://npsc.co.in',
                   baseDN: 'dc=npsc,dc=in',
                   username: 'user@npsc.co.in',
                   password: 'password' }

    var ad = new ActiveDirectory(config);
    var username = 'user@npsc.co.in';
    var password = 'password';

ad.authenticate(username, password, function(err, auth) {
  if (err) {
    console.log('ERROR: '+JSON.stringify(err));
    return;
  }

  if (auth) {
    console.log(auth);
    console.log('Authenticated!');
  }
  else {
    console.log('Authentication failed!');
  }
});
```

Comment: There are existing libraries that will help you with that task: http://ldapjs.org/ or https://www.npmjs.com/package/LDAP for example.

Comment: Hi@jblanco please see my updated question. I am getting error

Comment: ECONNREFUSED means you are not connecting to the server for some reason, double check the address and port, that the server is running, the credentials are right, the baseDN is the correct one, etc. If it still happens open an issue in their GitHub. Also, you don't need to declare the ad var twice, be careful when you copy/paste from the docs and double check what the code is doing...